How to Redefine and Correct Distortion Caused by an Incorrect UTM Projection in a Shapefile?
I have a shapefile generated from digitizing line features in a region within UTM Zone 10N. However, the digitizers incorrectly defined the projection of the digitized layer as UTM Zone 8N before starting the digitization.
How can I redefine the projection to the correct UTM Zone (10N) and fix the distortion caused by using the wrong projection definition?
Notes: The digitized layer appears correctly placed when its .prj file is updated to Zone 8N. However, the location shifts while preserving the same feature lengths. When the layer is projected to Zone 8N using projection tool in arcgis, it remains in the same place, but the feature lengths change.

Which projection tool did you use, the define projection or properties x,y coordinate system (which merely changes the assigned projection definition) or the projection tool (which, with a transformation, actually re-projects the layer?  If you used the correct tool but there were other problems in the digitization, there is a spatial adjustment tool to correct errors.

I used programming tools (pyproj, to_crs method in geopandas , and the projection tool in arc)
